# Creating new numpy matrix from list of rows of existing matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array `A`, and a list `x`. The elements of `x` are indices of the rows of `A`. I want to create a new matrix `B`, by taking the rows of `A` as indicated by `x`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `x` as an argument when indexing `A` to create your new matrix `B` as below. See [the docs here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))

x = [1, 2, 4]

B = A[x]

print(B)
# [[ 5  6  7  8  9]
# [10 11 12 13 14]
# [20 21 22 23 24]]
```